# Read data from all rows in column PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, row

I am doing some work that requires me to add the data from a specific column, say Column 1, to a PHP array. I can get the data from the first row in Column 1, but it stop there. How do I  collect that columns data from every row in the table?

Comment: SELECT RowName
      FROM Table

Comment: Ok @Stefan H... How do I display this data?

Comment: Display as in print the html?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to loop over the result set in a `while` loop:

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT...');

$data = array();
while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))) {
    $data[] = $row['columnName'];
}
```

Every call to `mysql_fetch_array` will get the next row of the result set. If there is no row anymore, it will return `null` and the loop stops.

The [*documentation*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) provides good examples.

**Update:**

Regarding duplicates: Either specify your SQL query correctly (preferred), e.g.

```
SELECT DISTINCT columnName FROM table
```

or use [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) after you fetched all the data:

```
$data = array_unique($data);
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, you wouldn't happen to know how I would remove duplicates from that array? Would you?

Answer (score 1):

```
    //Variable declaration as a small sql query
    $query = "select RowName FROM Table;";
    //Execute Query
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
                 //Do Stuff
             }
```